# Data not being Binded to recycler view

Tags: java, android, arraylist, cursor, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler View which is populated with an array list using data from a cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = getCursor(getContext().getContentResolver(), messageUri);
    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getContext(), Message_list);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        // The Cursor is now set to the right position
        Message_list.add(Message.getMessage(getContext(), cursor));
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Size Before" + Message_list.size());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

This works correctly with the data being inserted properly. However when i insert a new entry into the adapter, the adapter adds the row, but loads values from a random previous row i.e the text displayed in that row is text from another row present in the array list of items. Here is the insertion method:

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = messageText.getText().toString();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
            Message messageSMS = new Message();
            messageSMS.setBody(message);
            messageSMS.setAddress(number);
            messageSMS.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d(TAG, "" + messageSMS.getBody());
            Log.d(TAG, "Size After" + Message_list.size());
            mAdapter.add(messageSMS);
          mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(Message_list.size()-1);

        }
    });
```

And here is the add method inside the adapter:

```
public void add(Message item) {
    Message_list.add(Message_list.size()-1, item);
    notifyItemInserted(Message_list.size() - 1);
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: use this [adapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b)

Comment: @pskink I'm using an array list

Comment: and this is wrong approach, if you used a `ListView` (instead of `RecyclerView`) would you use `ArrayAdapter` or `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: I used the adapter from he link you sent me, now how do i add an item to it?

Comment: you dont,  the data is already stored in the Cursor

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `notifyItemInserted` just use `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding your item into Message_list.

Please refer [Document Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))

Comment: Use  Holder in your adapter.

Comment: Im using the view holder pattern as well, its a recycler view.